# Pop-up and font colour based problems in a form which is designed in Share Point.

Tags: sharepoint, colors, popup, sharepoint-designer

I am designing a system in Share Point via Share Point Designer. We have a form in my Share Point site. Users have to fill some fields in the form and send it to the approval committee. We cannot upload anything to the servers. The design is site based. Our problems are:

1- I want to add small  (?)  icons for the descriptions of that field. When the user click on the (?) icon for "brief description" field a pop-up or another window will be opened and perhaps it will say:

Enter a description of the requested thing.
Be as specific as possible.

2- I want to change the font colors of the fields in the form. The share point brings them black as default. Such as I want to see the "Brief description:"  and "Status:" as purple instead of black.

Brief description:   .....
Status:              .....

3- I want to add an agreement pop-up to the new form which will be open just after clicking "send" button in the form. The pop up will say:  "Are you sure that you read the procedure" . The user has to click "Yes" to continue sending the form. Otherwise It will return to previous screen again.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. You can upload the scripts to a document library and do pretty much whatever you want to the html after it is rendered by SharePoint.

For making changes from a custom form, [JSAPI](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/22/a-cross-browser-javascript-api-for-the-sharepoint-and-office-live-web-services/) may be useful. Alternatively you can hide a regular form and manipulate it with a popup.